# Is there a way to write 1-forms to matrices?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Consider the following Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$g=(1+y^2)dx\otimes dx+xy(dx\otimes dy+dy\otimes dx)+(1+x^2)dy\otimes dy $$

If $w^1$ and $w^2$ are 1-forms defined by
$$w^1=\sqrt{1+y^2}dx+\frac{xy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}dy, w^2=\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2+y^2}{1+y^2}}dy$$

then show that the Riemannian metric takes the form

$$g=w^1\otimes w^1+w^2\otimes w^2$$

Is there a way to convert $w^1$ and $w^2$ to  matrices? And also can someone please guide me the way? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: take $dx$ and $dy$ to be your basis vectors, and then convert to a matrix as you would for any vector space (technically free module).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just asking to clarify are they going to be 2x1 matrices, right?

Comment: they can be either row or column matrices, depending on how you're thinking about them.

Comment: Let's go to the next step. You're trying to write tge structure equations in matrix form? Edit your question to include this context/attempt.

Comment: I did the $\otimes$ for $w^1$ and $w^2$ and add them together. So the result is $\begin{bmatrix}y^2+1\\xy\\xy\\\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2+y^2}{1+y^2}}\end{bmatrix}$. The first three variables are same with the $g$ but the 4th not. Is this a coincidence that the first three are the sames as $g$ or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As linear functionals, write $$w^1 = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{1+y^2} & \dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\end{bmatrix}\quad \mbox{and} \quad w^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \sqrt{\dfrac{1+x^2+y^2}{1+y^2}} \end{bmatrix}$$Then $w^1\otimes w^1$ corresponds on the matrix level to $(w^1)^\top w^1$ and similarly for $w^2$. Thus, is your goal is to show that $$(w^1)^\top w^1 + (w^2)^\top w^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1+y^2 & xy \\ xy & 1+x^2\end{bmatrix}$$by directly computing the left side. You should be able to do this without running into any issues.

Comment: I guess I misguessed the point of this exercise. *Shrug*. Just a $1$-form as a linear functional.